# i cant responsive with javascript

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

I have written this code. When the screen size is changed, the classes I want are added and removed. Now, when the screen size is small, the change is done correctly, but when it returns to the previous state, it no longer works.

Now I have written this code. In IDE, there is a problem with the line I have written addListener. But I don't know what to do

```
<header class="desktopScreen d-flex bg-light align-items-center headerStyle">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <button class="login col-md-4 btnStyle"> ثبت نام</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-inline-flex justify-content-sm-between pe-5 ps-5 small text-center">
        <ul class="m-0">خانه</ul>
        <ul class="m-0">تماس با ما</ul>
        <ul class="m-0">انواع تورها</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 img-fluid text-center">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
    </div>
</header>

    <header class="mobileScreen d-flex bg-light align-items-center headerStyle d-none">
    <div class="col-6">
        <i class="fa fa-navicon ms-2"></i>
        <div class="mobileMenu">
            <div class="container text-start d-flex bg-light mobileMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li>خانه</li>
                    <li>تماس با ما</li>
                    <li>انواع تور ها</li>
                    <li>ثبت نام</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 img-fluid text-end">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo me-2">
    </div>
</header>
```

```
let screenMobileSize = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
let mobileScreen = document.querySelector('.mobileScreen')
let desktopScreen  = document.querySelector('.desktopScreen ')
 function mobileSize(screenMobileSize){
        if(screenMobileSize.matches){
                mobileScreen.classList.remove('d-none')
                desktopScreen.classList.add('d-none')
        }else {
                desktopScreen.classList.add(".d-none")
                desktopScreen.classList.remove(".d-none")

        }
 }
mobileSize(screenMobileSize)
screenMobileSize.addListener(mobileSize)
```

Comment: First removing and then adding the same class doesn't make much sense. Why don't you use the full set of [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries)? It would be trivial to set the styling as you seem to need with CSS.

Comment: @teemu Using CSS is a good suggestion. But I'm learning JavaScript, so I used this method.

Comment: Well, take a careful look at the else part, both of the class changes are targeted to the same element.